# Where do I use T-sql for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have used SQL Server a fair amount but always with SSMS.  I would like to be able to use all the capabilities and understand the environment better but I do not know where I use T-sql.  I have tried a few tutorials but they seem to gloss over this simple but important part; where do I input these commands?  Is it command line?  Is it some command line type GUI that should have installed with the SQL Server installation?  In this post (https://www.tutorialgateway.org/sql-attach-database/), there is a good example of just jumping into the commands but not specifying where these commands are input.  Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: In SSMS, have you ever tried `(database name)` -> right click -> `New Query`?

Comment: Yes Peter B. The point is that I think that there are ways to use it other than SSMS.  I have used queries extensively with SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where do I input these commands? Is it command line?

You can use these commands in a variety of tools that connect to SQL Server these include :

- SQL Server Management Studio.
- [SQLCMD (Command line tool)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)
- SQL Operations Studio, (Now SQL Azure Data Studio)
- Power Query tool in Excel.
- Powershell
- [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)
- [Toad for SQL Server](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-sql-server/)

Pretty much any tool that allows you to connect and issue SQL commands.

Answer (score -2):

`T-SQL` is the dialect of `SQL` used by SQL Server.  `SQL` is just a language standard.  Each vendor implement their own SQL.  SQL Server named its SQL as `T-SQL`.

The syntax is a bit different for different dialects.  Here's some info.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301038/what-are-the-differences-between-t-sql-sql-server-and-sql